# Canvas HTML5 datapoints to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I hope someone can guide me on how to convert long data points into arrays as i have a long list to plot and i hope of an easier way to loop instead of typing x 50 times.

Currently, i have data points where `x increment of +.25 and y is calculated from a formula below.`

Example:

```
dataPoints: [
{ x: 0, y: 1000*(0.5/(50*0.6))* (Math.exp(-((6)/(50*0.6)*0))) }
];
```

`Link to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QwZuf/95/`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple `for` loop:

```
var dataPoints = [];

for (var x = 0; x <= 12.5; x += 0.25) {
    dataPoints.push({ 
        x: x,
        y: 1000*(0.5/(50*0.6))* (Math.exp(-((6)/(50*0.6)*x)))
    });
}
```

and then pass that array as the `dataPoints` parameter to the plotting function.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/xQpv7/